# Uso de apiDoc Problemas con archivo apidoc.json

Tags: php, json, npm

necesito documentar API's y estoy probando con apiDoc. Segui un tutorial paso a paso. sin embargo me sale este tipo de error en el cmd [image: Problema]

apidoc.json... crear un archivo de configuracion apidoc.json el cual yo ya cree // Alguien tiene alguna solucion?

Comment: Creaste el archivo apidoc.json, ¿qué pusiste dentro?

Comment: Puse lo siguiente:

{
  "name": "APITEST",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Api de ejemplo",
  "title": "Título de la documentación de mi api",
  "url" : "http://api.test.com/v1"
}

Comment: Según el tutorial que seguí, se debía poner eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a colocar esto:

```
{
 "name": "TestApp" 
}
```

---

O sino este:

```
{
  "name": "Nombre",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Descripción",
  "title": "Titulo browser",
  "url" : "https://api.github.com/v1",
  "sampleUrl": "https://api.github.com/v1",
  "header": {
    "title": "Titulo header",
    "filename": "header.md"
  },
  "footer": {
    "title": "Titulo footer",
    "filename": "footer.md"
  },
  "template": {
    "withCompare": true,
    "withGenerator": true
  }
}
```

Comentas si sigues con el mismo problema

Comment: Gracias Andy Samuel... Ya me funciono!!!

Comment: Qué bueno que te haya servido, siempre que tengas más preguntas puedes volver a [es.so]. Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada dando click en el icono de aceptar(check) que aparece al lado izquierdo de la respuesta para dar por resuelta tu pregunta.